# Negative Barchart with Androidplot

Tags: android, bar-chart, androidplot

I'm using the `Androidplot` library to plot a Barchart to display something. 
The range of my values are **-40 till +40**.

How can I plot a bar to the negative side? I just want to center the zero on the y-axis in the middle and the bars should growing up or down, if the value is positiv of negativ. My bars are growing from the lower bound upwards. It should look like this:
[image]

Comment: I am trying to figure out a basic bar graph with Android plot, do you happen to have a basic sample code to do this?

Answer (score 1):

That works for me:

> plot.centerOnRangeOrigin(0);
>
> plot.setRangeLowerBoundary(0,BoundaryMode.AUTO);

Where plot is a instance of XYPlot.

Answer (score 1):

Negative bar support has recently been added to Androidplot **0.6.2**; you'll need to use the [latest development version](https://androidplot.jira.com/builds/artifact/ANDROIDPLOT-TRUNK/JOB1/build-latest/) to get it (it's very stable).

Once you have the correct version of Androidplot you can use Maria Reina's suggestion to enable the display of negative values.  Here's how I'm doing it in the screenshot below:

```
plot.setUserRangeOrigin(0);
plot.setRangeBoundaries(0, BoundaryMode.AUTO, 0,BoundaryMode.AUTO);
```

[image]

*Note :* There is currently a bug where if you are using overlay mode with 2 or more series and have negative bars, the overlay order of negative bars is reversed, causing the smaller negative values in a bargroup to be obscured by the larger ones.  If your goal is simply to reproduce the image above though then you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot i really needed this feature and didn't get why it wasn't working when using 0.6.1.

Comment: Just a little precision : BoundaryMode.AUTO is not mandatory here. You can also use BoundaryMode.FIXED  when you need to fixe your boundaries like `plot.setRangeBoundaries(min, max, BoundaryMode.FIXED);` where min is a negative value or not and this still works.

Comment: @Nick was something changed in a recent jar file to have this no longer work? I dowloaded the newest AndroidPlot 0.6.2 (androidplot-core-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT) and I am not able to get centerOnRangeOrigin to work as expected for me. centerOnDomainOrigin does work as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's a great question. I think there's no way to do that with the current version of AndroidPlot (0.6.0) with a single series of values.
I created a workaround in my project. I know it's not perfect, but it works: create two series that overlap, one in green and one in the background color. Suppose you have your currentValue to draw..

```
if (currentValue>=0) {
    greenRes[i] = Float.valueOf(currentValue);
    coverRes[i] = Float.valueOf(0);
}
else {
    greenRes[i] = Float.valueOf(0);
    coverRes[i] = Float.valueOf(currentValue);
}
```

In this way you always have the green bar starting from the zero axis and going up or down.

Comment: Could you please provide snippet of code on how you are using that ?